# How to use sql server like query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I only want to get all data from table start with sh, i use this query but it shows all data starts with 's'

```
  Declare @search varchar    
  Set @search = 'sh'    
  BEGIN    
    SELECT * FROM tbl_master WHERE Name LIKE @search+'%'    
  END
```

Comment: Did you try concatenating the % during the Set?

Comment: Did you try: WHERE Name LIKE CONCAT(@search,"%");

Comment: yeah..but not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you declare a variable as `varchar` - you get a `vachar(1)` - exactly **ONE** character long!

So if you assign `sh` to that variable, it really becomes just `s` ....

You need to **explicitly define** a length for your `varchar` - ***ALWAYS!***

```
 DECLARE @search VARCHAR(20)

 SET @search = 'sh'    

 SELECT * FROM tbl_master WHERE Name LIKE @search+'%'
```

Comment: Thats incorrect @Dimi. I think you're getting your SARGable concepts a bit mixed up.

Answer (score 0):

Please Specify **`Varchar Length`**

You can try also

```
  Declare @search varchar(10)    
  Set @search = 'sh'    
  BEGIN    
    SELECT * FROM tbl_master WHERE LEFT(Name,2) = @search
  END
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5bd1e/5)**